# Debug assertion failed in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am getting this error in visual studio:  Debug Assertion Failed!  Expression: (L"Buffer is too small" && 0)

It happens at the following lines of code:

```
program_name = (char *) malloc(strlen(argv[0])+1);
strcpy_s(program_name,sizeof(program_name),argv[0]);
```

It appears the size of the buffer it is trying to copy the character array to is too small but I am not sure why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(program_name)` returns the size of a pointer to `char`. That
is not what you want.
Replace that with `strlen(argv[0])+1` to pass the size of the allocated buffer.

However, also note that in C++, it would be better just to use `std::string`:

```
std::string program_name(argv[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I had just found it before I saw your answer.

Comment: @trueinViso: np, `sizeof(program_name)` will be `4` or `8` depending on whether you are on a 32-bit or 64-bit platform.